# Question regarding assumption in theorem on submanifolds of smooth manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry

We are given the following theorem:
Let $M^m$ be a $C^{\infty}$-manifold and $N \subset M$ a subset. Then the following three assertions are equivalent:

i) $N \subset M$ is a submanifold of codimension $m-n$.

ii) For each $p \in N$, there $\exists$xists a *neighbourhood V* of $M$, such that $f:V \to \mathbb{R}^{m-n}$ is a submersion and $f^{-1}(0) = V \cap N$.

iii) For each $p \in N$, there $\exists$xists *a neighbourhood V* of $M$ and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that there is an embedding $\psi:U \to V$ such that $\psi(U) = V \cap N$.

Now, my question is this: Since we are assuming that $M^n$ is a smooth manifold, we by assumption have a chart $$\mathcal{A} := \{(U_i,\varphi_i): i \in I\}.$$ But the neighbourhoods $V \subset M$ in (ii) and (iii), are they *not* neccessarily associated with a chart in $\mathcal{A}$? The proof of one of the directions ((iii) $\to$ (i)) makes me think we are **not** assuming that this is the case, i.e. that there exists an $i \in I$ such that $U_i = V$.

Edit: So, in the beginning of the direction (iii) $\to$ (i), I want to justify explicitly why we can take $U,V$ smaller in $\psi:U \to V$ so that $V$ is in a chart $(V,\varphi)$ and so that $\psi:U \to V$ is still an embedding.

Comment: Right. The neighborhoods called $V$ can be any neighborhoods, not necessarily taken from any particular atlas.

Comment: But how do I know that there is a $\tilde{V} \subset V \subset M$ such that $(\tilde{V},\varphi) \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Unless I miss something obvious, I would have to justify it by the fact that  $\mathcal{A}$ is really an equivalence class $[\mathcal{A}]$ of $C^{\infty}$-atlases that are equivalent if any two charts in the two given atlases are $C^{\infty}$-compatible.

Comment: You don't know that. If you just have an atlas (not a maximal atlas  or something like that) every chart might be huge. $\mathbb R^n$ is a manifold, and one atlas for it consists of just the single chart $(\mathbb R^n,$identity map).

Comment: Why do you want charts with such small domains $\tilde V$?

Comment: I think  I see the source of the confusion. In (ii), the author neglected to say "there exists a smooth function $f$." As it stands, $f$ is unspecified, and you probably assumed it meant that $f$ should be (the restriction of) a function from a given atlas. But that would make $f$ map into $\mathbb R^m$, not $\mathbb R^{m-n}$, so it can't be the intention.

Comment: If f is a submersion it is smooth by the definition of a submersion so I don’t think that is important. 

Here I am talking about the proof of the direction (iii) $\to$ (i). We are given an embedding $\psi:U \to V$, and according to the author we might have to shrink $U,V$ to find a new $V = \tilde{V}$ so that our new $V$ is in a chart with respect to the atlas on $M$. Now, I want to justify first why we can find such a $V$ and why this new $\psi:U \to V$ with $\tilde{U} = U$ and $\tilde{V} = V$ is *still* an embedding.

Comment: (1) The issue in (ii) isn't the absence of "smooth" but the absence of "there exists". (2) Your latest comment asks about part of a proof that I haven't seen, so I can't comment on it. How to prove that(iii) implies (i) also depends on other aspects of the source, like "are maximal atlases available?" and "which of the many equivalent definitions of "submanifold" is meant in (i)?" So I'm not going to try to dig further into this. (In view of the sloppy formulation of (ii), I wouldn't be terribly shocked if you've found a real problem in the proof.)

Comment: No worries, I think the issue has been solved. If you are interested, we define $N \subset M$ as a submanifold of codimension $m-n$ if for all $p \in N$ there exists a chart $(U, \varphi)$ of $M$ ($M$ $C^{\infty}$-manifold by assumption) such that $\varphi(U \cap V) = \varphi(U) \cap (\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \underbrace{\{0\}}_{\in \mathbb{R}^{m-n}}).$$